# IntelliJ Idea Maven Native Library

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14 Community Edition on Windows 7.
I have a Maven project which depends on a native library (dll). This dependency is set in the pom.

Is there a way for IntelliJ to import this native library automatically. So I do not have to copy it manually to the project directory when I want to start the project.

Before I used Eclipse and all dependencies were copied to the target directory, so I always started my project from the target directory, which worked fine. Where does IntelliJ store the dependencies?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you asking about idea capabilities or maven capabilities?

Comment: IntelliJ capabilties. Or a general how do you use a native library from a Maven repository in IntelliJ.

Comment: You have your main class unpack it from the jar to a temp location, and load it dynamically at runtime (at least thats how I did it). It's not straightforward

Comment: Do you do this manually or do you automate it with a Maven command? I want it automated and at best do not touch the pom.xml so the pom.xml is not IDE specific.